# Как выбрать сим карту при звонке через ADB на деайсе от Самсунг?

Tags: android, adb

Есть Самсунг с двумя сим картами, нужно с каждой проверить баланс через ADB shell *100#. Никак не получается позвонить со второй сим карты, перепробовал уже все, что смог нагуглить, но вызов все равно осуществляется всегда через первую симку.
Для звонка использую команду:
*adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d *100%23**

через --es добавлял различные параметры из списка ниже

> [
> "extra_asus_dial_use_dualsim",
> "com.android.phone.extra.slot",
> "slot",
> "simslot",
> "sim_slot",
> "subscription",
> "Subscription",
> "phone",
> "com.android.phone.DialingMode",
> "simSlot",
> "simSlotId",
> "slot_id",
> "simId",
> "simNum",
> "phone_type",
> "slotId",
> "slotIndex",
> "slotIdx"
> ]

Указывал значение 0 и 1, пробовал менять subscriptionId, ничего не помогает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов сделано